# ColdFusion FilegetMimeType giving inconsistent results

Tags: coldfusion, mime-types

I need to use the `FilegetMimeType()` function, and I tested it in a program called `demomimetype.cfm`.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset reploc = '#cookie.moxlog#'>
<cfset extrepoc = ExpandPath('#reploc#')>  
<cfset typegif = FilegetMimeType('#extrepoc#/brightpink1.gif')>
typegif brightpink1.gif #typegif#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

This program returns the result that typegif is "image/gif"  which is exactly correct.  When I add the lines

```
<cfheader name =   "Content-Disposition"  value="attachment;#extrepoc#/logo106">
<cfcontent type="#typegif#" file="#extrepoc#/brightpink1.gif">
```

I get this result:

[image: Image of correct download]

This is what I was hoping for, although `demomimetype.cfm` is not what I chose to open.  However, this screen does open `brightpink1.gif`, so I'm okay with it.

Then I tried to integrate this into my actual system using this program, which results from a submit in an earlier program:

```
  <cfoutput>
  <cfset col       = form.thecol>      
  <cfset colarray = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('xcol')>
  <cfset origval  = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('#col#')>
  <cfset attname  = origval[1]>      
  <cfset extreploc = ExpandPath("#cookie.moxlog#")>        
  <cfset typeatt   = FilegetMimeType('#extreploc#/#attname#')>     
  </cfoutput>
```

The variable "attname" will be "brightpink1.gif.  When I output typeatt I get "application/octet-stream", which is not correct.  And when I add the lines

```
 <cfheader name = "Content-Disposition" value="attachment;#extreploc#/#attname#">
 <cfcontent type="#typeatt#" file="#extreploc#/#attname#">
```

I get the wrong result -- not surprising because the mimetype is wrong:
[image: Image of wrong result]

Obviously the demo is working correctly, and the real application is not.  I have tried making the filename in the demo to be a variable, and the demo goes on working.  I have tried making the filename in the application specific, and it still does not work.

I don't want to use the "strict" parameter because some of the files do not have extensions, even though they are of a specific type like `.jpg`.

There must be some reason why the code in the demo works and the nearly identical code in the application does not.  But I cannot see it.  Can anyone figure out what is going on here?

Comment: Good job providing details. Is your demo and application running in the same environment? If not, explain the differences. Have you tried hard coding the entire path for the FilegetMimeType call to a copy of the gif used in your demo?

Comment: Hi Dan,Yes they are both running in the same environment.  The demo is working correctly.  I can try hardcoding the entire path in the real application, and see if any info turns up.

Comment: @Dan writing out the path explicitly fixed the application code.  I wonder why.   Do you have any idea?  I think I can proceed with the application that way, although I have to change the explicit path for the production environment.

Comment: @BettyMock - Print out the dynamic path on screen and compare it to the hard coded path. Any differences?

Comment: @ageax I did that and there were no differences.  Further info is: the original environment is Lucee, but when I put it up online the environment is Cold Fusion.  The generalized version with #extreploc# instead of a hardcoded path worked in ColdFusion.  So it seems to be a Lucee bug.

Comment: *although demomimetype.cfm is not what I chose to open*  The content-disposition header is incorrect. It's missing `filename=` and the value should be a file name, not an absolute path. i.e. Something like this `<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=""brightpink1.gif""">`

Comment: Oooh... that explains it. Using different engines/versions in Dev and Prod always leads to headaches ;-)  Look into [commandbox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox). It makes it very easy to download and install specific versions of CF.

Comment: Regarding, `although I have to change the explicit path for the production environment.`, not necessarily.  You could use if/else logic to set the value of a variable.

Comment: So what's an example of the actual path (not variable) that works in CF but not Lucee?

Comment: @DanBracuk -- I have done that kind of thing all over the place.  I was more musing on the fact than considering how to implement it.

Comment: @Ageax I don't know it off the top of my head.  I'll check it out shortly.

Comment: @ageax the path for CF  /home/moxwareo/public_html/reports/demo ; this is CF10 / Centos.  The Lucee path is /opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/reports/#cookie.moxlog# with Ubuntu.

Comment: @BettyMock - Hm... say the cookie value was "myFolder", are you saying it worked on Lucee when you hard coded the path to "/opt/lucee/.../myFolder" - but did NOT work when you used "/opt/lucee/.../#cookie.moxlog#"? Since there's a variable involved it might not be evaluating to the same thing. To verify it one way or the other, I'd print out the evaluated path character by character - just to be sure they're really the same.

Comment: @BettyMock instead of `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>`, why not code it `<cflocation url="#extreploc#/#attname#">` instead?

Comment: @user12031119 Interesting idea  -- I'll check out whether it works for that situation -- there are complications...

Comment: @ageax I think it was the #extreploc# that caused the problem, not the #cookie.moxlog#.  Anyway, it's working fine in Coldfusion,which is where the production system is.